# How to keep my Tex interpreter running?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tex-core

I'm coding with Vscode and XeLatex. When running the code below, it worked and cost approximately 20s

```
\documentclass[border={0pt}]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz,}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    [%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        box/.style={rectangle,draw=black,thick, minimum size=28pt},
    ]%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\foreach \y in {0,2,4,...,100}{
    \foreach \x in {0,1,...,100}
        \node[box,fill=black] at (\x,\y){};  
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

But when it comes to the code like this (which I suppose takes the double computational complexity), it would run for no more than 30s and automatically turned off.

```
\usepackage{tikz,}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    [%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        box/.style={rectangle,draw=black,thick, minimum size=28pt},
    ]%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\foreach \y in {0,2,4,...,100}{
    \foreach \x in {0,1,...,100}
        \node[box,fill=black] at (\x,\y){};  
}
\foreach \y in {1,3,5,...,99}{
    \foreach \x in {0,2,...,100}
        \node[box,fill=red] at (\x,\y){};  
}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: VScode appears this in the first 20s]
[image: and stop at some point around 25s]
[image: finally failed]

How can I make it run for 20 seconds more to make it, or it just me misunderstood the information fed back by Tex?
If there is anything ambiguous please tell me. Thanks for your help!!

Comment: TeX will just run until it's done. In online systems such as Overleaf, there is a 'wrapper' that will kill long jobs, but on a local system, usually you just do that yourself :)

Comment: you seem to be running from python, your call to tex from there must be setting a timeout as tex itself will loop forever  if that is specified. So you will need to change your  python settings somewhere

Answer (score 1):

Remarks:

- Nodes are highly inefficient just for drawing rectangles. There is a rectangle operator just for this job.
- Using `\foreach` inside one `\path` (or `\fill`, \draw`, ...) is more efficient (file size) than creating a path for each loop iteration.
- Simple stripes do not need a nested loop.

Code example with much better runtime and file size:

```
\documentclass[border=0pt, tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[black]
    \foreach \y in {0,2,4,...,100}{
      (0, \y) rectangle +(101, 1)
    }
;
\fill[red]
  \foreach \y in {1,3,5,...,99}{
    \foreach \x in {0,2,...,100}{
      (\x, \y) rectangle +(1, 1)
    }
  }
;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The example can be improved further (left as exercise for the reader):

- First draw the red vertical stripes, then the black horizontal stripes on top of it. This removes the nested loop for the red boxes.

[image]

Comment: thanks for your help! :)